# SQL, Comparing relationships housed in multiple link tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

(I'm having a hard time even explaining this question)

I have 5 Tables, `A`, `AZ`, `Z`, `BZ`, `B`.

`AZ` represents a Many-to-Many relationship between `A` and `Z`.
`BZ` represents a Many-to-Many relationship between `B` and `Z`.

I would like a result set that is `A B` where `B` is linked to the full set of `Z` for a given `A`.

So, let's say that `Z` is a Tag table and contains:

```
Tag1
Tag2
Tag3
```

`A` is an Object Table and contains:

```
ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
```

`B` is a Widget Table and contains:

```
WidgetX
WidgetY
WidgetZ
```

`AZ` contains:

```
ObjectA  Tag1
ObjectA  Tag2
ObjectB  Tag3
ObjectC  Tag2
ObjectC  Tag3
```

`BZ` contains:

```
WidgetX  Tag1
WidgetX  Tag2
WidgetY  Tag2
WidgetY  Tag3
WidgetZ  Tag3
```

I want my result set to be:

```
ObjectA  WidgetX
ObjectB  WidgetY
ObjectB  WidgetZ
ObjectC  WidgetY
```

Is this doable in a query, or should I pull back some intermediate sets of data and iterate in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, major edit to rejigger this based on your feedback. It's a little kludgy, but here you go:

```
select distinct
    x.aid,
    x.bid
from
    (select
        az.aid,
        bz.bid,
        (select COUNT(1) from az az1 where az1.aid = az.aid) as acount,
        (select COUNT(1) from bz bz1 where bz1.zid in (select zid from az az1 where az1.aid = az.aid) and bz1.bid = bz.bid) as bcount
    from
        az
        inner join bz on
            az.zid = bz.zid
    ) x
where
    x.acount = x.bcount
```

It uses nasty subqueries to get the right counts, and then limits our rowset based on your criteria.

Comment: That's not the correct result set.  ObjectA is linked to Tag1 and Tag2.  WidgetY is not linked to Tag1, so ObjectA to WidgetY is not valid.

Comment: @JacobG - Try to use better table names and actual data in the future, believe it or not these examples make helping all the more difficult.

Comment: @JacobG - Okay, fixed to be correct...let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @Eric - That's a winner.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Major edit:

As Andriy rightly points out, I had the wrong end of the stick on my first go. This should do better:

```
select a, b.b
from az cross join b
left outer join bz on az.z = bz.z and b.b = bz.b
group by a, b.b
having sum(case when bz.b is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The cross join sets up a table that expresses an assumption that every b satisfies the condition for every a in AZ. The left outer join checks this assumption and leaves a null value in the bz.b column where that assumption fails. The having clause excludes those a-b pairings that contain one or more such nulls.

Comment: From how I understand the question, an object's set of tags should be a subset of a widget's in order for the object to match the widget. Your query would return too many matches.

Comment: +1, I was contemplating something along the lines of this yesterday before giving up to sleepiness. Only I was thinking about cross joining to `(select distinct b from bz)` rather than to `b`, but that wouldn't affect the results and might possibly be less efficient.

Comment: +1 This one works as well.  Though it is orders of magnitude slower than Eric's solution.  Good strategies for me to play with.  Thanks!